# PDF of $X+Y$ for $X$ and $Y$ independent with given PDFs

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Consider two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Let $f_X(x)=1-\frac{x}{2}$ if $ 0 \leq x \leq 2$ and $0$ otherwise. Let $f_Y(y)=2-2y$ if $ 0 \leq y \leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise. Find the probability density function of $ X + Y$.

**Attempt**

for $0 \leq a \leq 1$ we have 
\begin{align}
f_{X+Y}(a)=\int_0^a f_Y(a-x)f_X(x)dydx =\int_0^a\left(2-2(a-x)\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)dx\\
=\left. \left( 2x-2ax+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{ax^2}{2}-]\frac{x^3}{3}\right)\right|_0^a
\\=2a-\frac{3a^2}{2}+\frac{a^3}{6}
\end{align}

When I try to attempts for $ 1 \leq a \leq 2$ and $2 \leq a \leq 3$ I can't seem to know which boundaries I should take for my integral. I made myself a draft of the boundaries but nothing that I attempt works, if someone could explain me why and the theory of the boundaries for the other 2 regions I would be glad.

Comment: The key is to write correctly every PDF you meet, and in the present case, to include the conditions in the functions. Thus, $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are defined *on the whole real line* by $$f_X(x)=(1-x/2)\mathbf 1_{0<x<2}\qquad f_Y(y)=(2-2y)\mathbf 1_{0<y<1},$$ and, *for every real $a$*, $$f_{X+Y}(a)=\int_\mathbb Rf_X(x)f_Y(a-x)dx=...$$

Comment: Thus, for every real $a$, $$f_{X+Y}(a)=\int_0^2(2-x)(1-a+x)\mathbf 1_{a-1<x<a}dx.$$ If $a<0$ or $a>3$ the intervals $(0,2)$ and $(a-1,a)$ do no meet hence $f_{X+Y}(a)=0$. If $0<a<1$, $$f_{X+Y}(a)=\int_0^a(2-x)(1-a+x)dx.$$ If $1<a<2$, $$f_{X+Y}(a)=\int_{a-1}^a(2-x)(1-a+x)dx.$$ And, if $2<a<3$, $$f_{X+Y}(a)=\int_{a-1}^2(2-x)(1-a+x)dx.$$ Care to finish this?

Comment: Perfect that definitely help me, now I understand better how to set it up, the case of $0 \leq a \leq 1$ was a trivial one and I needed help for the others. Thank you!

Comment: Update:

I was able to do two more problems of similar nature now, wish my book was as clear as you!